# How to determine the bounds in marginals fx(x) and fy(y)?

Tags: probability, integration

I have $f(x,y) = 24xy$ for $0 < x < 1$ and $x^2 < y < x$.

I want to find the marginals in $x$ and $y$, but I'm not sure what the bounds would be.

For the marginal in $x$, would the bounds be between $x^2$ and $x$ or $0$ and $1$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Draw a picture, including the line $y=x$ and the parabola $y=x^2$. To find $f_X(x)$, we "integrate out" $y$. The picture will tell you $y$ goes from $x^2$ to $x$, for the joint density "lives" in the part of the first quadrant that is above $y=x^2$ and below $y=x$.

Comment: I thought that was right, but when you do the expected value of y, do the bounds change to 0 and 1 then? @AndréNicolas

Comment: Do you mean $E(X)$? If you are using the marginal just computed, note that it is valid for $0\lt x\lt 1$, so you integrate $xf_X(x)$ from $0$ to $1$. Same for $E(Y)$, except we have not discussed the marginal of $Y$. **However**, if we find $E(X)$ by finding the double integral of $xf_{X,Y}(x,y)$, then we integrate over the region above $y=x^2$ and below $y=x$.

Comment: I meant when you integrate to find E(Y) by taking the integral of yfy(y), do you use the same bounds we used when finding fx(x) because both integrals have y bounds @AndréNicolas

Comment: We can find $f_Y(y)$ in the same way as we found $f_X(x)$. We integrate out $x$, and $x$ will go from $y$ to $\sqrt{y}$. This density function for $Y$ is valid $y=0$ to $1$, so if we are finding $E(Y)$ that way, we integrate $yf_Y(y)$ from $0$ to $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture, including the line $y=x$ and the parabola $y=x^2$. The joint density function "lives" in the part of the first quadrant that is above $y=x^2$ but below $y=x$.

So when we find $f_X(x)$ by "integrating out" $y$, $y$ travels from $y=x^2$ to $y=x$. We get
$$f_X(x)=\int_{x^2}^x 24xy\,dy$$
for $0\lt x\lt 1$. The density function is $0$ outside the interval $(0,1)$.

You did not ask, except tangentially in a comment, about $f_Y(y)$. This is calculated by "integrating out" $x$. Here $x$ travels from $y$ to $\sqrt{y}$.

For finding $E(X)$, or $E(Y)$, we have two alternatives. One way to find $E(Y)$ is to calculate
$$\int_0^1 yf_Y(y)\,dy.$$
But we can bypass the density function entirely. For
$$E(Y)=\iint_K (y)(24xy)\,dy\,dx,$$
where $K$ is the region above $y=x^2$ but below $y=x$. This can be calculated as an *iterated integral*, integrating first with respect to $y$ from $x^2$ to $x$, and then integrating with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$.